# Convert model objects in OrderedDict to Json django

Tags: json, django, serialization, django-rest-framework, deserialization

```
In [32]: obj
OrderedDict([('code', 'COO21'),
             ('name', 'sai'),
             ('country', <Country: INDIA>)])

Error:-
TypeError: Object of type Country is not JSON serializable
```

Not able to convert model objects in ordered dict to json

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Override the `to_representation()` method in your `serializer` to customize the response when sending back to the view/controller.
`instance` is the object of the serializing model.

```
    def to_representation(self, instance):
        ret = super().to_representation(instance)
        ret["country"] = instance.country.name if country else None
        return ret
```